# perl listen to a port number to check status

Tags: perl, port

I have a daemon, for which, I need to check the status and see if it is up or down. As of now, I am using an expect script to telnet to the port and see if it is alive. I am looking to rewrite it in perl, to check the same. Any pointers to modules or features that I can use is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[http://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::PortState](http://metacpan.org/pod/IO%3a%3aSocket%3a%3aPortState)
would be a good place to start. There might be better solutions, but this is what I am using.

Answer (score 2):

For quickly checking a single port, [`Net::EmptyPort`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::EmptyPort) provides `check_port`, or it's simple enough to do it yourself with [`IO::Socket::IP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::IP). Both are less hassle than using `IO::Socket::PortState` for just one port (which describes its own interface as “complex”).

With `Net::EmptyPort`:

```
use Net::EmptyPort qw<check_port>;

if (check_port 5432)
{
    # ...
}
```

But if you look at what that's doing, you may decide you can as easily make the socket connection yourself, along the lines of:

```
use IO::Socket::IP;

my $socket = IO::Socket::IP->new(PeerAddr => 'localhost', PeerPort => 5432);
if ($socket)
{
  $socket->close;
  # ...
}
```

That also lets you provide other arguments, such as `Timeout` to adjust how long it waits before giving up and deciding that the port isn't in use. For `localhost` you may be able to get away with a much shorter time-out than the default; I've used 100 ms without problem.